# How can I go about loading Mule ESB onto a AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, mule

I need to upload it to EC2 and am unsure how to go about it. I am using Eclipse with the Mule plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there have you try [CloudHub](https://cloudhub.io/)?

It's basically Mule in the Cloud

Comment: Hello. Yes I have. This is a fairly big project and a lot of people are not comfortable trying something mainly because we don't have a very lenient deadline.

Comment: @KieranHanna But using CloudHub (which runs on EC2) would speed things up, since you don't have to deal with setting Mule up.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply follow the installation guide from the documentation and that should be it.

Please see:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Downloading+and+Installing+Mule+ESB#download-MuleCommunityRuntime

Answer (score 1):

There's a ready made and up to date Docker container that can simplify things for you: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/vromero/mule/

After starting the container, just drop your Mule application ZIPs into `/opt/mule/apps`.

There are other notable mount points: make sure to [read the user guide to learn more](https://github.com/vromero/mule-docker#usage).